missing vaapih265enc in gstreamer-vaapi
I installed vaapi using apt install gstreamer1.0-vaapi on Debian 12 linux system. But the vaapih265enc is missing in the feature list.
 # gst-inspect-1.0 vaapi
Plugin Details:
  Name                     vaapi
  Description              VA-API based elements
  Filename                 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvaapi.so
  Version                  1.22.0
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gstreamer-vaapi
  Documentation            https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/vaapi/
  Source release date      2023-01-23
  Binary package           gstreamer-vaapi
  Origin URL               https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gstreamer-vaapi

  vaapidecodebin: VA-API Decode Bin
  vaapih264dec: VA-API H264 decoder
  vaapih264enc: VA-API H264 encoder
  vaapijpegdec: VA-API JPEG decoder
  vaapimpeg2dec: VA-API MPEG2 decoder
  vaapimpeg2enc: VA-API MPEG-2 encoder
  vaapipostproc: VA-API video postprocessing
  vaapisink: VA-API sink
  vaapivc1dec: VA-API VC1 decoder

  9 features:
  +-- 9 elements

It shows the vaapi version is 1.22.0, it looks very new released version. I think encoder H.265 should be included. Can you advise how to add vaapih265enc?
